# Apple rules regarding checking for valid network connection

Tags: ios, networking, app-store

I have heard a lot about Apple's rules on checking for a valid network connection. I am using Apple's Reachability example to do this. My question: is it enough to run this check once the app loads or does it have to be done every time my app wants to connect to the internet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You don't have to check at all**! However, it will probably provide a bad user experience if you don't provide some sort of fall back for lack of a valid network connection.

I usually implement a *timeout* rather than relying on Reachability.

If you are set on using Reachability, I would suggest creating a wrapper for it so that you can just call something like:

```
[MyReachability hasInternet];

+(BOOL) hasInternet
{
    Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
    [reachability startNotifier];

    NetworkStatus status = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];

    if(status == NotReachable) 
    {
       return NO;
    }
    else if (status == ReachableViaWiFi)
    {
        return YES;
    }
    else if (status == ReachableViaWWAN) 
    {
        return YES;
    }
    //etc.
}
```

Comment: Thanks James. Good to know before app store submission.